# Create Woocommerce product on submission of form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

i have 'contact form 7' form and I have a number in a nearby span with class 'btQuoteTotalCalc'. On submission of this contact form, I want to capture the number using javascript/jQuery, then create a woocommerce product using the number as the price and redirect the user to the checkout page. Am writing all this code in a new custom plugin. However when I test by submitting the form, nothing happens and there is no error in browser dev console or server php error log.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form#wpcf7-f731').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get the number from the nearby span with class 'btQuoteTotalCalc'
        var price = parseFloat($('.btQuoteTotalCalc').text());

        // Create a new WooCommerce product
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-json/wc/v3/products',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                name: 'Product Name', // Replace with your desired product name
                type: 'simple',
                regular_price: price,
                status: 'publish'
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('YOUR_WC_KEY:YOUR_WC_SECRET'));
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // Redirect the user to the checkout page
                window.location.href = 'https://silkwoodstudios.co.uk/checkout/';
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And yes, I did enqueue it in my plugin main file:

```
function custom_woocommerce_plugin_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (is_page('product-photography')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-woocommerce-script', plugins_url('custom_woocommerce_plugin/custom_woocommerce_script.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_woocommerce_plugin_enqueue_scripts');
```

And yes, I did put in the api key and secret.

Comment: So what actual response is your AJAX request getting?

Comment: I kinda doubt the `/wp-json/wc/v3/products` will let you create products without any form of authentication? The whole approach seems really rather flawed, it sounds like nothing much would be stopping me from creating a product with any arbitrary price I wanted to, if you actually got this working like you intended. (Not sure if WC allows for _negative_ prices even, but if it did, I would probably get you to owe _me_ money.)

Comment: @CBroe There is no response in the console. Regarding authentication, there is API key and secret generated in Woocommerce settings.

Comment: Yes, but you would be giving those credentials away in client-side code with that approach. It is not called a _secret_ for nothing - you are supposed to keep it that way, secret. Hidden from the eyes of people (your site visitors) who should not have it in the first place.

Comment: I guess that's right, but it should still work to begin with. I have another approach which also doesn't work if you would like to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809419/create-woocommerce-product-on-submission-of-a-form-along-with-a-custom-price-fet)

Comment: I think user must have permissions to do that or assign author maybe ?

Comment: Is your api key read/write permissions ? Also try running ajax php function instead?

Comment: @Snuffy Yes, it has read/write permission. I have tried Ajax PHP function. Could you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809419/create-woocommerce-product-on-submission-of-a-form-along-with-a-custom-price-fet) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810536/create-woocommerce-product-on-submission-of-a-contact-form-7)

Comment: I think on both you are redirecting before the product is created. Remove the redirect and see if the product is created also check $_POST what data have since you will create product only if there is price.