# Create Woocommerce product on submission of a Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have 'contact form 7' form and I have a number in a nearby span with class 'btQuoteTotalCalc'. On submission of this contact form, I am capturing the number using javascript, then create a woocommerce product using the number as the price and redirect the user to the checkout page. Am writing all this code in a new custom plugin. However when I test by submitting the form, nothing happens and there is no error in browser dev console or server php error log.

js file:

```
// Function to capture the number from the page
function captureNumberFromPage() {
    var numberElement = document.querySelector('.btQuoteTotalCalc');
    
    if (numberElement) {
        var number = parseFloat(numberElement.innerText);
        return number;
    }

    // Return null if number not found
    return null;
}

// Attach a function to the wpcf7mailsent event
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    // Capture the number from the page
    var capturedNumber = captureNumberFromPage();

    // Check if a number is captured successfully
    if (capturedNumber !== null) {
        // Make an AJAX request to the server to create the WooCommerce product
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=create_woocommerce_product');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                // Redirect the user to the checkout page
                window.location.href = 'https://example.com/checkout'; // Replace with your actual checkout page URL
            }
        };
        xhr.send('price=' + capturedNumber);
    } else {
        console.log('Number not found on the page.');
    }
}, false);
```

main plugin php file:

```
// Function to create a WooCommerce product
function create_woocommerce_product() {
    if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
        $product_data = array(
            'name' => 'Custom Product', // Replace with the desired product name
            'type' => 'simple',
            'regular_price' => $_POST['price'], // Use the captured number as the product price
            'description' => 'This is a custom product.', // Replace with the desired product description
        );

        // Create the product
        $product_id = wc_create_product($product_data);

        if ($product_id) {
            echo 'Product created successfully.';
        } else {
            echo 'Failed to create product.';
        }
    }

    // Always exit to prevent any extra output
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_create_woocommerce_product', 'create_woocommerce_product');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_create_woocommerce_product', 'create_woocommerce_product');
```

And yes, I did enqueue the js file in main plugin php file.

Comment: What have you debugged so far?

Comment: @Bhautik There is an error 500 in console. It points to the js file. And the error is 'failed to load resource...'. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/qxsjHM3) for this line `xhr.send('price=' + capturedNumber);`

Comment: Please refer this - [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)